# How to calculate the size of resources as present in the network of mozilla and chrome

Tags: javascript

A website contains lots of resources like js, images, css etc.I need to find the individual resource size information for website. Already get the resource timing details from `window.performance.getEntries();` . but it has no details about the size . please help me. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually there should be info about size as mentioned here: [w3.org - transferSize](http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/#widl-PerformanceResourceTiming-transferSize), but I can't find this property in my Chrome `47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)`.

Perhaps, it will be added later, because now it still have status "**Working Draft** 25 November 2015".

*Anyway, thank you for interesting question :)*

Comment: I've seen that transferSize. i am not get in Mozilla and chrome. Can see  [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/transferSize) no support when check compatibility for browser.